# Cannot stack multiple push notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, push-notification, notifications

I am working on a code to push notifications to the browser. My code to display notifications look like below

```js
const imageWithTextNotification = (reg) => {
            // more options at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification#Syntax
            const options = {
                icon: "imgs/notification.png",

                // 07 - Notification with a body
                body: "Alert!! This is image notification",

                // 09 - Actions on notification click (see sw.js for log)
                actions: [
                    { action: "search", title: "Try Searching!" },
                    // 10 - More Actions
                    { action: "close", title: "Forget it!" },
                ],
                data: {
                    notificationTime: Date.now(),
                    githubUser: "hhimanshu"
                }
            }
            reg.showNotification("Counter=" + counter++, options)
        }
```

After reading the documentation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Replacing_existing_notifications), the code should stack multiple notifications since I am not using the `tag` property in the `options` object.

However, in my observation, multiple notifications do not stack. The same notification is replaced (see counter value increased in the demo below). Please see below

[image: web push notification]

The reproducible codebase is available at https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hellman-8q4t3 and the demo is available at https://8q4t3.sse.codesandbox.io/

I have tested this on

```
Google Chrome => Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Firefox => 75.0 (64-bit)
```

Could someone please help me understand how can I get the multiple stacked notifications?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also in touch with @gauntface on twitter and with his help, I was able to fix this issue.

[Here is the Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/gauntface/status/1248463654770507777)

And here is the solution
[image: Stack Push Notifications]

Comment: Can you post the updated code in case the twitter link goes away?

Comment: Hey Nick, the code remains the same. It's just the change on how alerts are displayed on Mac

Comment: Gotcha - I hadn't realised what was going on in the image.